How to build a mobile pwa in Angular v17 /How to get the mobile screen dimensions in the browser?
I just want the Angular preview in my bowser to look like the mobile form factor, not the default one that just fits to the size of your monitor. Is there a way to set a limit so that new components auto fit to the set size?
I tried using CSS but that did not work.
@media (max-width: 768px) {
}

What are you trying to do, exactly ? If you want to see the preview, you can change the windows size using the brower settings (developer options).  https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2016/04/16/set-size-of-browser-inner-window-for-screenshots-in-chrome/
What you did in CSS won't work.
@media (max-width: 768px) { } --> @media rule targets devices with a maximum width of 768 pixels. Any CSS rules placed inside the curly braces { ... } will only apply when the viewport width is 768 pixels or less. So if you use your PC screen, you won't notice any difference.

Thanks for the idea with Chrome Dev Tools. I forgot that there was an option like this.
